# install plugins to eclipse ide in headless mode

Tags: eclipse

I need to use an eclipse for JEE developers then install numerous plugins then repeat on 3 separate platforms.   Is there a command line or headless way to load or install these plugins without starting the IDE, going to market place, or install software, restart and start again?

Maybe an eclipsec way or something?

I would like to script this build as I keep forgetting to include plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see [Eclipse Help - *Installing software using the p2 director application*](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html):

> ...
>
> The following example shows the command line used to install CDT
>   into the SDK.
>
> ```
> <targetProductFolder>/eclipsec.exe 
>    -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 
>    -repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/
>    -installIU org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group/<version> ...
> ```
>
> ...

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for an answer:

This task can be solved using the console version of the oomph installer https://github.com/a-langer/eclipse-oomph-console. It allows you to install Eclipse in headless mode (from command line) with a set of required plugins.